# Is there any way to poll messages from topic using Spring Cloud Function approach?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We're using `SubscribableChannel`, `MessageChannel` and `PollableMessageSource` and configured using `@EnableBinding` and `@StreamListner`. Now we need to migrate to functional approach. `SubscribableChannel` and `MessageChannel` can be converted using Consumer and Supplier beans but we're not able to migrate `PollableMessageSource`.
Since functions are disabled if we use `@EnableBinding`, hence we're stuck for migration. We tried looking into `@PollableBean` but seems it works only for Reactive Supplier with finite streams. Is there any way of doing it?
Ref: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a function and a `PollableMessageSource` in a bean and bind to it using `@EnableBinding` instead of binding to the function. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/blob/master/applications/sink/tasklauncher-sink/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/tasklauncher/sink/TaskLauncherSinkConfiguration.java for an example.

Comment: We need to remove @EnableBinding and use only functions. Found that it is not yet supported.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1956